# Problems while web scraping with golang

Tags: http, go, web, url, web-scraping

I'm creating a web scraper with golang and I just wanted to ask some questions about how most of them work. For example, how does Googlebot not use a lot of bandwidth when scraping because you have to go to each URL to get data and that can be thousands of URLs so not only will that take bandwidth, it will also take a lot of time. I'm building a web scraper and I'm experiencing these issues and I wanted to ask what the best way of fixing these issues is. https://github.com/hackermondev/cosmic

Comment: The Googlebot uses lots of bandwidth and time. A big part of the Googlebot secret sauce is the prioritization of the pages to crawl.

Comment: This won't solve everything, but just looking at your code I'll recommend to understand and utilize the reader / writer interfaces.  In your code you're using ioutil.ReadAll, which means that you are waiting to read the entire response body before you start processing it.  You can process a response while reading it, for example you can pass an http response body (which is a ReadCloser) directly to [html.NewTokenizer](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html#NewTokenizer) which will read the html and emit tokens which you can filter to find all links in the page.